# Jetpack Compose: Passing state down

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I've got the following Composables:

```
 @Composable
fun CreateScreen(
    state: CreateParcelViewModel.State,
    confirmAction: (Form) -> Unit = {}
) {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = { CreateAppBar(backAction) },
        contentWindowInsets = ScaffoldDefaults.contentWindowInsets,
        content = { contentPadding ->
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(contentPadding)
            ) {
                CreateForm()
            }
        },
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(onClick = { confirmAction }) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Check, contentDescription = "Ok")
            }
        })
}
```

CreateForm:

```
@Composable
fun CreationForm() {
    var formResult by remember { mutableStateOf(Form("", "")) }

    OutlinedTextField(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp)
            .onPreviewKeyEvent {
                if (it.key == Key.Tab && it.nativeKeyEvent.action == ACTION_DOWN) {
                    focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down)
                    true
                } else {
                    false
                }
            },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Next),
        value = formResult.trackingCode,
        onValueChange = { value: String -> formResult = formResult.copy(trackingCode = value) },
        label = {
            Text(stringResource(id = R.string.parcel_code))
        },
        singleLine = true,
        trailingIcon = {
            IconButton(onClick = {
                Timber.i("Scan")
            }) {
                Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_barcode), contentDescription = "Scan barcode")
            }
        },
        supportingText = {
            Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.code_helper_text))
        }
    )
    OutlinedTextField(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp)
            .onPreviewKeyEvent {
                if (it.key == Key.Tab && it.nativeKeyEvent.action == ACTION_DOWN) {
                    focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down)
                    true
                } else {
                    false
                }
            },
        singleLine = true,
        value = formResult.parcelName,
        onValueChange = { value: String -> formResult = formResult.copy(parcelName = value) },
        label = {
            Text(stringResource(id = R.string.parcel_name))
        },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Next),
    )
}
```

with Form being:

```
data class Form(
    val trackingCode: String,
    val parcelName: String
)
```

There are more fields in the form but it's not relevant, just that it's a big one.

Now I want to call `confirmAction()` when clicking on my FAB by passing in my `Form` object, but if I put my mutableState property up in the Scaffold level, then I cant pass it down to CreateForm.

I could of course put a `onChange()` callback for all my form inputs but this is a big form, I would be passing down 20 callbacks... is there a better way to do this?